# How to make a momentary button in tkinter with Python 3.6

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I need to have a momentary button in tkinter but if I use `<Button-1>` or `<ButtonPress-1>` the function to change the color doesn't seem to run until after I release. For example I have a button that would starts red, when pressed need to turn green, and when released it turns back to red.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.on_offButton = Button(text="ON/OFF", font=('Helvetica', 20), bg='red')
        self.momentaryButton = Button(text="Momentary", font=('Helvetica', 20), bg='red')
        self.on_offButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.momentaryButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.on_offButton.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_offEvent)
        self.momentaryButton.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.momentaryPressedEvent)
        self.momentaryButton.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.momentaryReleasedEvent)
    def on_offEvent(self, event):
        if self.on_offButton.cget('bg') == 'green':
            self.on_offButton.config(bg='red')
        elif self.on_offButton.cget('bg') == 'red':
            self.on_offButton.config(bg='green')
    def momentaryPressedEvent(self, event):
        if self.momentaryButton.cget('bg') == 'red':
            self.momentaryButton.config(bg='green')
        elif self.momentaryButton.cget('bg') == 'green':
            self.momentaryButton.config(bg='red')
    def momentaryReleasedEvent(self, event):
        if self.momentaryButton.cget('bg') == 'red':
            self.momentaryButton.config(bg='green')
        elif self.momentaryButton.cget('bg') == 'green':
            self.momentaryButton.config(bg='red')
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `activebackground` specifies the background of the button while the button is pressed. Buttons also have the option `command` to specify what needs to be done when the button is pressed, so bindings are not needed. This way, your code simplyfies to:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.on_offButton = Button(text="ON/OFF", font=('Helvetica', 20), bg='red', command=self.on_offEvent)
        self.momentaryButton = Button(text="Momentary", font=('Helvetica', 20), bg='red', activebackground='green')
        self.on_offButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.momentaryButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
    def on_offEvent(self):
        if self.on_offButton.cget('bg') == 'green':
            self.on_offButton.config(bg='red')
        elif self.on_offButton.cget('bg') == 'red':
            self.on_offButton.config(bg='green')

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note: `mainloop()` runs till the users destroys the `root` so `root.destroy()` is not needed.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. And thank for the advise on using command instead of bind as well.